# Solving $max \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 (\phi_i A_{ij} \psi_j)^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-decomposition

Could you please provide some hints for me to solve this optimization problem?

Here, for any $i=1,2$ and $j=1,2$, $\phi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are unknown vectors, $\alpha_i$, $\beta_j$ are some known vectors, $A_{ij}$ is matrix. The optimization problem is

$\max_{\phi_i,\psi_j} \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 (\phi_i' A_{ij} \psi_j)^2$

$s.t. \phi_i'\phi_i = \psi_j'\psi_j=1$, for any $i=1,2$, $j=1,2$
and $\phi_i'\alpha_i = \psi_j'\beta_j=0$, for any $i=1,2$, $j=1,2$

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context? Where does this optimization problem come from? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: A potentially helpful observation: your objective function can be written as $\|M\|_F^2$, where we can take either
$$
M = \pmatrix{\phi_1 & 0\\ 0 & \phi_2}' \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}} \pmatrix{\psi_1 & 0 \\0 & \psi_2}
$$
or 
$$
M = \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}} \pmatrix{\psi_1 & 0 \\0 & \psi_2}\pmatrix{\phi_1 & 0\\ 0 & \phi_2}'
$$

Comment: Do you have any idea of how we could approach this in the case that we don't have the $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ constraints?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for the comments. 1 Actually, I encounter this problem as a pure math problem. I haven`t have any practical explaination of it so far. 2 I am trying to solve it by Lagrange multipliers and still working on it. 3 It looks like a singular value decomposition problem. But there are constrains on the length of every one of $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$. I have no idea of how to deal with it, even though with help of $||M||^2_F$. 4 And sorry to say that I have no idea about how we can solve it without the $\alpha_i$, $\beta_j$ constraints.

Comment: And may I ask why do you mention the case without $\alpha_i$, $\beta_j$ constraints? Do you have any further observations?

Comment: If this is a "pure math" problem, then why are you interested in it? Do you have any reason to suspect that it has a nice solution?